# 401-Unauthrized when downloading file for Google Team drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to access Team drive files using Drive Picker.

But I am getting this error

```
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

So I tried to check in Google API Explorer and called the API by passing `fileId` and `supportsTeamDrives = true`. But in Google API explorer also, its giving me the same error.

What I am missing here?[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Accessing [Teamdrives](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/teamdrives) uses a different method. List the files of the particular Teamdrive using the method [`Teamdrives: list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/teamdrives/list), from there you will be able to get the Teamdrive `id` from the response just like below:

```
{
   "kind": "drive#teamDrive",
   "id": "XXXXXXIDXXXXXXX",
   "name": "TheFileName"
}
```

You can then use the specific file `id` to get the metadata of a specific file from the method [`Teamdrives: get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/teamdrives/get).

Comment: Tramdrives: get returns the metadata of team drive. Not file's metadata. To get file's metadata, we have to stick with files: get as per the documentation